# Spark Streaming for Fitbit data

Tags: apache-spark, oauth-2.0, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, fitbit

I am doing Fitbit Oauth 2.0 to access fitbit data. I am storing this data in SQL db after which, I am using Spark SQL to analyze the data.
If I have to use Spark Streaming, how do I ingest data to Spark after doing OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it

1. You can format the fitbit data to structured data and then dump it onto HDFS/Kafka/Socket and start a corresponding HDFS/Kafka/Socket receiver.
2. You can write your own custom receiver to receive the data directly using OAuth or from SQL db.